# Javascript format number for converter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created unit converter for Length,time,Mass etc using jquery.
I am facing problem with formatting final output.I want four digit after decimal point.Even if number is exponential.

I found Click [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_number.asp) for formatting but facing following problem.

toFixed(x): IF i pass 4 and number is 0.000005 then output will 0.0000 that is wrong.It is also append extra 0 to make it desire length.

If i apply toExponential(x) then toFixed(x) to get desired output then I'm not getting any result.

```
var final_result=0.00054354578000;
var test=final_result.toExponential();
alert(test.toFixed(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

**[JS FIDDLE DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/haK5K/2/)**

**[JS FIDDLE DEMOE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/haK5K/3/)**  for exponential

You missed using [NUMBER()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) which allow you to work with numerical values

```
var final_result=0.00054354578000;
var test=Number(final_result);
var Result=test.toExponential();
 alert(Result);
var aData=Number(Result)
alert(aData.toFixed(4));
```

Comment: If you take 0.00054354578000 number then output should be 5.4354e-4

Comment: @Dhruv: Tell me what exactly output you want to be ?? check my 2nd demo it alerts  `5.4354e-4`